# Who is Rittenhouse in the TV Show “Timeless?”

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dialogue, timeless

I just finished watch *Timeless* (2016-18) and my question is who is  Rittenhouse?

I am deaf and watch with closed captioned but the problem is they change too much.

So who is actually Rittenhouse?

Comment: [Who is Rittenhouse?](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Rittenhouse_(Timeless)#:~:text=Rittenhouse%20is%20a%20shadowy%20cabal,vision%20protagonist%20Rufus%20Carlin%20specifically)